# getting an image of current google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know how can i get the static image of my currently displayed google map. I have used this code to get the googl map in a div

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script> 
function initialize() { 
    var mapOptions = { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
    zoom:1,
    scrollwheel:false,
    disableDefaultUI: true, 
    draggable: false

    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
```

I amm using thise url to get the static image

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0,0&zoom=1&size=750x425&sensor=false&visual_refresh=true&scale=1

However i am not getting the image same as the one displayed by the function.

Comment: <div id="map-canvas" style="width:750px;height:425px;" ></div>

Answer (score 0):

The maximum allowed width/height without a business-license is **640px**

What you can do: use a scale of 2, set the zoom to 0 and for width/height use the half size:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0,0&zoom=0&size=350x212&sensor=false&visual_refresh=true&scale=2

Note:  the result will not be exactly the same, because the zoom is different. You'll see different labels(at zoom 0 e.g. you'll see no labels)